# Zend 2 adapter in Controller works fine but not in Model

Tags: php, model, zend-framework2, adapter

I am new in Zend 2.
I have made a controller and Model.

I am getting the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\websites\zend2\module\Pages\src\Pages\Model\PagesTable.php on line 25

What do i do wrong?!?!

SOLUTION:

controller:

```
namespace Pages\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

protected $pagesTable;

function indexAction() {
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'pages' => $this->getPagesTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

public function getPagesTable()
{
    if (!$this->pagesTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->pagesTable = $sm->get('Pages\Model\PagesTable');
    }
    return $this->pagesTable;
}
}
```

Model:

```
namespace Pages\Model;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class PagesTable  {

protected $tableGateway;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;

}

public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    return $resultSet;
}

}
```

Add
Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Pages\Model\PagesTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('PagesTableGateway');
                $table = new PagesTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'PagesTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                return new TableGateway('pages', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the functin `getServiceLocator()` is a function that is implemented in the [`AbstractController`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php#L242) which `AbstractActionController` extends from, which then again you are extending your Controllers from.

The `ServiceLocator` itself is injected by the ServiceManager.

The way you wanna be doing things is like this:

```
// SomeController#someAction
$table = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyTableGateway');
$pages = $table->pages();
```

A very clean and slim Controller. Then you set up a Service for `MyTableGateway`

```
// Module#getServiceConfig
'factories' => array(
    'MyTableGateway' => function($serviceLocator) {
        $dbAdapter = $serviceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $gateway   = new MyTableGateway($dbAdapter);
        return $gateway;
    }
)
```

This Factory will call your class `MyTableGateway` and then use Constructor-Injection to inject the Dependency, which in this case is `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`.

All that's left for you to do is to modify the `__construct()` of your `MyTableGateway` to allow for the DbAdapter-Parameter and you're done. That way you gain access to the DbAdapter inside your Gateway and the code is all clean and separated ;)

Comment: Wow this is rocketscience for me :-) How come the Controller and Model to look over. : - $

Comment: I don't understand your question, please rephrase it :)

Comment: Sorry. I mean where should I place the code. Can you help me a little bit further :-)

Comment: First code-sample, as pointed out inside the sample, goes into your controllers action. Second code sample, as pointed out inside the sample, goes into the `getServiceConfig()` of your `Module`-Class' return array

Comment: I have add the code. Is this what you mean? Then i am getting this error: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for MyTableGateway

Comment: You have to try to understand what you are doing...  please read carefully what i wrote. Your ServiceManager can't find MyTableGateway because you just copied the stuff i wrote 1:1 - you need to modify this to your needs! You do not have a class "MyTableGateway", in your case it's likely to be PagesTable...

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what your writing and how to setup a ServiceManager.

Comment: found the solution. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yep, looks very clean like this. You now implemented the full TableGateway. What i did was just "clean up" the code you have provided into the respective areas of how to approach this with ZF2. Your Solution works very well tho! ;)

Comment: I must be honest. I copied the code. Now I have to go to understand hahaha ;-)